# GitHub pages 404 File Not Found error

Tags: github, github-pages

I am attempting to publish a website using github pages. I have a `Index.HTML`, and see the message "Your site is published at https://starsweeper.github.io/" in the repository settings, but when I go to the page I see the message

> 404 
>   File not found
>   The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

Here is the repository: https://github.com/starSweeper/starSweeper.github.io 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You appear to have resolved this issue? It's unclear whether this was just formatting in your post, but `Index.HTML` should be all lowercase. ie. `index.html`.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, I didn't realize the file names were also case sensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the problem was the incorrect casing of `Index.HTML`. This should be all lowercase. ie. `index.html`.

> I didn't realize the file names were also case sensitive.

The case-sensitivity, in this case, is dependent on the underlying operating system. Linux/unix is case-sensitive, Windows is not. But URLs are always case-sensitive.